# Wrong top offset of CSS Button in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am working on my new site and I checked it in multiple browsers: ie6+, chrome, safari and firefox.

I noticed that firefox display the top offset of my button in wrong position - like top=-1 and I cant fix it in NORMAL way...

Here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/7XRZG/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button` inputs and `text` inputs seem to have different default vertical align properties in firefox. Try explicitly setting them to the same thing. For instance:

```
<input type="text" style="height:19px;border:1px solid silver;font-size:10px;vertical-align:text-top;">
<input type="button" value="Search" style="margin-left:5px;background-color:#f5f5f5;color:#707070;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;font-size:9px;padding:0 10px;height:21px;font-weight:700;vertical-align:text-top;">
```

Comment: It fixes the firefox problem but cause the same problem in ie6. I know I can make CSS condition to detect if IE6 - but still I want to see if there's a better solution

Comment: I am glad that I no longer have to support IE6 on my sites. Maybe if you try different values for `vertical-align` it will fix: middle, top, bottom, baseline, etc.

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` fixed in firefox and caused nothing in ie6. so this is the solution. thank you!